I'm trying to open a component from header. I tried Routes. When I click on the linked icon, it adds /componentName to local host and nothing happens
App.js
import Heading from './Components.js/Heading.js'
import './App.css'

function App () {
  return (
    <div>
      <Heading />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App

index.js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom"
import Payment from './Components.js/Payment.js'
import Trolley from './Components.js/Trolley.js'
import './index.css'
import App from './App.js'`

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" component={<App />} />
        <Route exact path="/Component.js/Trolley.js" component={Trolley} />
        <Route exact path="/Component.js/Checkout.js" component={Payment}/>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
)

Heading component
import React from 'react'
import { React Icon } from 'react-icons/'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

function Heading () {
  let pagetitle = "Page Title"
  return (
    <nav> 
      <div>
        <Link to="/App"></Link>
        <Link to="/App"><h1>{pagetitle}</h1></Link>
      </div> 
      <div>
        <Link to="/Trolley">React Icon</Link>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Heading

Here's the component I'm trying to display
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

function Trolley () {
  let pagetitle = "Page Title"
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <nav> 
          <div>
            <h1>{pagetitle}</h1>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div>
          <button>
            Shop More
          </button>
          <div>
            <Link to="./Payment.js">Pay Now</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
  
export default Trolley

I tried using routes. I expected the Trolley component to be displayed when I click on the icon. However, the display didn't change. App continued to be rendered, the trolley component was not displayed.

Edit: I think its a typo, /Component.js/Checkout.js needs to be /Component.js/Payment.js
I would assume you have to change your routes from:
<Route exact path="/" component={<App />} />
<Route exact path="/Component.js/Trolley.js" component={Trolley} />
<Route exact path="/Component.js/Checkout.js" component={Payment}/>

to:
        <Route exact path="/" component={<App />} />
        <Route exact path="/Component.js/Trolley.js" component={<Trolley />} />
        <Route exact path="/Component.js/Checkout.js" component={<Payment />}/>

If this still doesnt work, you might have to change the paths of the components so it would look like this:
import Trolley from './Trolley';
import Payment from './Payment';

...

  <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
  <Route path="/trolley" element={<Trolley />} />
  <Route path="/checkout" element={<Payment />} />

I think this should fix your issue
